# Checkbox to copy selected cells only and paste to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, cell, worksheet

I'm not very advanced in this however I'm hoping to obtain some direction. I'm currently running the following VBA:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If (CheckBox1.Value = True) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B13:E18").Copy
    End If

If (CheckBox2.Value = True) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B20:E25").Copy
    End If

If (CheckBox3.Value = True) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B27:E32").Copy
    End If
    
If (CheckBox4.Value = True) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B34:E39").Copy
    End If

    'copy the chunk above for more check boxes

End Sub
```

However, it only ends up copying the last selected checkbox instead of multiple cells at once. What am I missing in order to copy only selected cells per a checkbox and copying them over to another worksheet within the same workbook?

Comment: If the intent is to copy B13:E18 and B20:E25 and etc., you need to use Union to construct a range that includes each of the target ranges that you want. Then do the copy on the 'Unioned' range.

Comment: Is this code on a userform or in  worksheet code module?

Comment: @Tim Williams: They said it basically works, so must be in a userform, no?

Comment: Could be a worksheet...

Comment: @Tim Williams: Ok. Must vary with versions of excel. I can't run code in an older version (2010) as code in a worksheet. It only works in a userform. For the purpose of my edification, I'll test in the appropriate version. Can you tell me what version does it work in?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crude but working example:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rgCopy As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        If CheckBox1 Then
            Set rgCopy = .Range("B13:E18")
        End If
        
        If CheckBox2 Then
            If rgCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rgCopy = .Range("B20:E25")
            Else
                Set rgCopy = Union(rgCopy, .Range("B20:E25"))
            End If
        End If
        
        If CheckBox3 Then
            If rgCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rgCopy = .Range("B27:E32")
            Else
                Set rgCopy = Union(rgCopy, .Range("B27:E32"))
            End If
        End If
        
        If CheckBox4 Then
            If rgCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rgCopy = .Range("B34:E39")
            Else
                Set rgCopy = Union(rgCopy, .Range("B34:E39"))
            End If
        End If
    End With
    
    If Not rgCopy Is Nothing Then
        rgCopy.Copy
    Else
        MsgBox "nothing selected message"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Ranges Depending on Checkboxes' Value

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyChkBoxConsecutiveRanges(ByVal chkBoxes As Variant)
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sfrgAddress As String = "B13:E18"
    Const sGap As Long = 1
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "A2"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = RefChkBoxConsecutiveRanges( _
        sws.Range(sfrgAddress), chkBoxes, sGap)
    'Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dfCellAddress)
    
    ' Copy
    If Not srg Is Nothing Then
        srg.Copy dfCell
    End If
    
End Sub

Function RefChkBoxConsecutiveRanges( _
    ByVal sfrg As Range, _
    ByVal chkBoxes As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal sGap As Long = 0, _
    Optional ByVal SearchOrder As XlSearchOrder = xlByRows) _
As Range
' Needs `RefCombinedRange`.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = sfrg.Worksheet
    Dim srOffset As Long
    srOffset = IIf(SearchOrder = xlByRows, sfrg.Rows.Count + sGap, 0)
    Dim scOffset As Long
    scOffset = IIf(SearchOrder = xlByRows, 0, sfrg.Columns.Count + sGap)
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = sfrg
        
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = LBound(chkBoxes) To UBound(chkBoxes)
        If chkBoxes(n) Then
            Set srg = RefCombinedRange(srg, scrg)
        End If
        Set scrg = scrg.Offset(srOffset, scOffset)
    Next n
    
    If Not srg Is Nothing Then
        Set RefChkBoxConsecutiveRanges = srg
    End If
    
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to a range combined from two ranges.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefCombinedRange( _
    ByVal CombinedRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If CombinedRange Is Nothing Then
        Set RefCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set RefCombinedRange = Union(CombinedRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

**Userform Module e.g. `UserForm1`**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim chkBoxes As Variant
    chkBoxes = Array(CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4) ' add more
    CopyChkBoxConsecutiveRanges chkBoxes
End Sub
```